# (de)serialize an property of an object without getting the rest of the object

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, customization

I am trying to write a semi-transparent wrapper around an existing class, and I would like it to be able to mimic the serialization of the other class.

For instance, given the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(CustomConverter)]
    string Foo;
}
```

I would like my object's custom serializer to serialize its own `Foo` property using the `CustomConverter` specified by `Foo`. I need it also to handle other things like the `ObjectCreationHandling` specified and used by JSON.Net.

Is there a way to basically tell a `JsonSerializer` "deserialize to this type, but as if it was a this property on this object", or do I have to manually look up the attributes and set the settings accordingly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it appears, is through creative use of `IContractResolver`. If anyone else is curious, I can try to post my full solution once I finish it.